# Finding memories solutions for playing audio online j2me

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, java-me

I'm a new programmer working on j2me apps, I'm trying to create app to play music online, connect to server is and streaming is Ok. However, I got a problem about manage the memory. The memories in feature phone is quite small, so after stream it is able to read about 1M at one time, but audio file that I expect is about 30MB. So what is the solution for this issue.
ps// I tried to using thread but that is quite bad because interruption between change the threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option for streaming with JavaME is to use the RTSP protocol. But I don't know what it requires to set that up.

If you insist on using HTTP, you can have one thread fetch the data while another thread is playing. Looks like you can test that method with this app:
http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Video/J2MEStreaming-28778.shtml

Comment: thank for your response, it seem to be easy. However, I myself try to dig that way, it still not do. The main thing is that the process change the data that store in ByteArrayInputStream to player. In my point of views, 
-1st thread get the date and put it in the ByteArrayInputStream. Meanwhile, other one is wait for data(even though it still start).
Then, when thread one process data, thread 2nd using it to play, but at that time memories still not free so thread 1 must be waited. => So with this procedure it creates the delay time. Any demo solution code help me?

Comment: I have not tried implementing streaming that way. You could download a Java decompiler, and take a look at the source in the streaming app I linked to (and hope it isn't obfuscated).
I don't think, however, that it's possible to make a smooth streaming with JavaME. There'll always be a little "hickup" when switching between threads, except on a very few high end phones.

Comment: If it was me who had to make a streaming app, I would look into setting up a RTSP server instead. I know that RTSP works on even older phones, like e.g. Sony Ericsson W800: Just input the RTSP URL in the walkman player, and it streams. Not 100% sure about support from JavaME though, but I would expect the Player object to be able to play a RTSP URL the same way.
You could experiment in your LAN. Set up e.g. VLC Media Streaming as a RTSP server, and try to access it with a Player object from JavaME.

Comment: Correction: Input the RTSP URL in the browser, not the walkman player. If it plays, then the device supports the RTSP protocol. Next try to open the same URL with a Player object.